I have an error with compileDebugKotlin and can't fix it
My error is:
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: <Error class: unknown class>
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.JvmPlatformAnnotationFeaturesSupport.isRepeatableAnnotationClass(JvmPlatformAnnotationFeaturesSupport.kt:22)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.AnnotationChecker.isRepeatableAnnotation(AnnotationChecker.kt:320)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.AnnotationChecker.checkPropertyUseSiteTargetAnnotations(AnnotationChecker.kt:145)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.AnnotationChecker.check(AnnotationChecker.kt:48)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.ModifiersChecker$ModifiersCheckingProcedure.checkModifierListCommon(ModifiersChecker.java:225)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.ModifiersChecker$ModifiersCheckingProcedure.checkModifiersForDeclaration(ModifiersChecker.java:183)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.DeclarationsChecker.process(DeclarationsChecker.kt:106)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.BodyResolver.resolveBodies(BodyResolver.java:258)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer.analyzeDeclarations(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.kt:227)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer.analyzeDeclarations$default(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.kt:58)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:119)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:77)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:256)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:247)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:247)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:87)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:165)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:50)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:104)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:48)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:463)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:62)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.doCompile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:477)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:400)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileNonIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:281)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:125)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:657)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1624)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)


Execution failed for task ':app:compileCoreDebugKotlin'.

A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
Internal compiler error. See log for more details

build.gradle.kts (project)
    import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

    plugins {
        alias(libs.plugins.android).apply(false)
        alias(libs.plugins.kotlinAndroid).apply(false)
        alias(libs.plugins.ksp).apply(false)
    }

build.gradle.kts (app)
    import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.pm20.util.archivesName
    import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
    import org.jetbrains.kotlin.konan.properties.Properties
    import java.io.FileInputStream

    plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinAndroid)
    alias(libs.plugins.ksp)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinSerialization)
    }

...

    dependencies {
    implementation(libs.kotlinx.serialization.json)
    api(libs.kotlin.immutable.collections)
    implementation(libs.androidx.multidex)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    implementation(libs.androidx.swiperefreshlayout)
    implementation(libs.androidx.print)
    implementation(libs.bundles.room)
    ksp(libs.androidx.room.compiler)
    api(libs.joda.time)
    api(libs.material)
    api(libs.gson)
    }

libs.versions.toml:
[versions]
#jetbrains
kotlin = "1.9.23"
kotlin-immutable-collections = "0.3.6"
#KSP
kotlinxSerializationJson = "1.5.1"
ksp = "1.9.23-1.0.19"
#Androidx
multidex = "2.0.1"
print = "1.0.0"
constraintlayout = "2.1.4"
swiperefreshlayout = "1.1.0"
#Room
room = "2.6.1"
#Material
material = "1.11.0"
#jodaTime
jodaTime = "2.12.5"
#gson
gson = "2.10.1"
#Gradle
gradlePlugins-agp = "8.5.2"
[libraries]
#Material
material = { module = "com.google.android.material:material", version = "1.12.0" }
#Helpers
joda-time = { module = "joda-time:joda-time", version = "2.12.7" }
gson = { module = "com.google.code.gson:gson", version = "2.11.0" }
#Android X
androidx-constraintlayout = { module = "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout", version.ref = "constraintlayout" }
androidx-multidex = { module = "androidx.multidex:multidex", version.ref = "multidex" }
androidx-print = { module = "androidx.print:print", version.ref = "print" }
androidx-swiperefreshlayout = { module = "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout", version.ref = "swiperefreshlayout" }
#Room
androidx-room-runtime = { module = "androidx.room:room-runtime", version.ref = "room" }
androidx-room-ktx = { module = "androidx.room:room-ktx", version.ref = "room" }
androidx-room-compiler = { module = "androidx.room:room-compiler", version.ref = "room" }
#Kotlin
kotlinx-serialization-json = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json", version = "1.7.1" }
kotlin-immutable-collections = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-collections-immutable", version = "0.3.7" }
[bundles]
room = [
    "androidx-room-ktx",
    "androidx-room-runtime",
]
[plugins]
android = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "gradlePlugins-agp" }
ksp = { id = "com.google.devtools.ksp", version.ref = "ksp" }
kotlinAndroid = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
kotlinSerialization = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization", version.ref = "kotlin" }

I have checked and updated all dependencies, cleared the cache, asked Chat GPT and googled the errors. I can't find a solution.
It used to work, but I've changed a lot since then and don't know what the problem could be.
Apart from the error, I don't get any more information, not even when I run it with debug
